# Specify a database name for a django model

Tags: django, psql

Here is my problem :

i have a django class :

Fiber in a Data app.

So it gives me a :

Data_fiber table in postgres.

using uppercase is really painful in psql and gives me a lot of error.

Is there a way to define the table in my Fiber model ?

Regards

Comment: Why is your app/module name uppercase https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @iklinac i was not at the begining of the project ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Meta` in your module to specify table name

```py
class Meta:
    db_table = 'data_fibier'
```

docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#db-table